# Extending polyline to intersection point using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

I have a polyline shapefile, would like to extend the polyline to the intersection point of the nearby polyline and snap using Python in QGIS.

Comment: I'm thinking the best way to do this is to create a line on the same angle from the first/last segment with your extension tolerance, use as a spatial query to select intersecting lines then intersect each selected geometry in turn, calculate the distance to each intersection point from the line end, using the closest then move/add the point to the line. It's a bit of work but I can't see an easy way.

Comment: is there anyway to do like that?

Comment: do you want to do this for all the polylines in the map?

Comment: Yes. I want to do for all polylines.

Comment: well, you might need to code in python(the hard way) using the idea mentioned by @MichaelMiles-Stimson

Comment: look at [Create Intersecting lines and remove dangles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116502/create-intersecting-lines-and-remove-dangles/116751#116751)

Comment: Also see 'How to extend grid lines'... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111875/how-to-extend-grid-lines-survey-traverse-lines-created-by-vector-grid-tool-in/111900#111900